# Flash: Components doesn't work in CS5, works in CS4

Tags: flash, components, flash-cs5, cs4

I've spent most of the day trying to convert my SWC based components to FLA based, and I've got everything working except for the live preview - the display simply cycles between the two frames (avatar and skin) continuously.

After a lot of tries, I've loaded up the component in Flash CS4 and the live preview works correctly, I've confirmed this also with a sample component I've downloaded.

Has anyone come across this issue before? are there any changes to the way live preview should be implemented from CS4 to CS5? or could this be an issue with my copy of CS5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to your question today.
I think what we have is the problem of following the directions.

1. Drag combobox to stage.
2. Double click component.
3. Select desired skin  eg. up skin.  ( may be in frame 2)
4. In the properties inspector, adjust position, size, color effect, ect.
5. Control -> Test Movie -> Test

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've found out that the problem was me trying to get a reference to a class in the library during live-preview, which apparently is not possible, I ended up creating a sort of hybrid component that doesn't use a live preview